# Unix how to Kill Job create by me

Tags: unix

I have run some jobs using `nohup` in my UNIX box using putty yesterday and today. I am not able to found those jobs when using `jobs -l`. I want to find my jobs running status ? and How to kill the jobs if I don't remember my PID.

Comment: It will be automatically goes into background. Use : `ps -ef | grep 'processname'` to find PID of process.

Comment: as per you mention processname but i have found servername 11282 10990  0 04:26 pts/4    00:00:00 grep processname where is PID in this number and how to kill the process.

Comment: i try to kill 10990 and entered the command and re-entered ps -ef | grep 'processname' same result is displayed

Comment: `processname` means here your command/program name.

Comment: Thanks Sat but i still facing same issue i will explain what i am doing i am new to unix program as you told ps -ef | grep 'processname' i got some 11282 10990 0 04:26 pts/4 00:00:00 grep  and i am trying to kill  10990 i don't know is it correct please explain steps

Comment: i executed command ps auxwww|grep -i 'server' and getting all job and finding my job also but not able find PID

Comment: Use: `ps -eo pid,user,cmd,comm | grep 'ssh'` . In the output, first numeric part is PID of the process. Then, Use : `kill 9876` to kill a process. Here, `9876` is a dummy PID.

Comment: Thanks Sat finaly i able to understand the pid and kill process

Comment: Glad it worked for you..